# How to name systemd mount unit properly?

Tags: centos, mount, centos7, systemd

I'm trying to automount CephFS after boot via systemd

I've got the next unit:

```
[Unit]
SourcePath=/etc/fstab
DefaultDependencies=no
After=remote-fs-pre.target
After=network.target
Wants=network.target
After=network-online.target
Wants=network-online.target
Conflicts=umount.target
Before=umount.target

[Mount]
What=ceph-node1:6789,ceph-node2:6789,ceph-node3:6789:/dev
Where=/mnt/cephfs-dev
Type=ceph
Options=name=devuser,secretfile=/etc/ceph/cephuser.secret

[Install]
WantedBy=remote-fs.target
```

As I know `Where=` setting must match unit name. I do next:

```
[root@centos system]# systemd-escape -p --suffix=mount '/mnt/cephfs-dev'
mnt-cephfs\x2ddev.mount
[root@centos system]# vi /etc/systemd/system/mnt-cephfs\\x2ddev.mount
```

But something went wrong:

```
[root@centos system]# systemctl status mnt-ceph\\x2ddev.mount
● mnt-ceph\x2ddev.mount - /mnt/cephfs-dev
   Loaded: error (Reason: Invalid argument)
   Active: inactive (dead)
    Where: /mnt/cephfs-dev
     What: ceph-node1:6789,ceph-node2:6789,ceph-node3:6789:/dev

May 05 10:07:12 centos.imoldovan-lpt systemd[1]: mnt-ceph\x2ddev.mount's Where= setting doesn't match unit name. Refusing.
```

How to name unit properly? Obviously the problem with a dash in mount point `/mnt/cephfs-dev` but I need exactly this mount point.

Comment: So change the name of the unit to match the mount point.

Comment: The unit is alredy have right name "mnt-cephfs\x2ddev.mount" but I still have got an error

Comment: That's not the name of the unit given in your question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To put some closure to this:

The problem was that `mnt-ceph\x2ddev.mount` was a typo. It should have been `mnt-cephfs\x2ddev.mount` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Mount units must be named after the mount point directories they control.
Example: the mount point /home/lennart must be configured in a unit file home-lennart.mount.

Mount]
What=/dev/vdc
Where=/a/b/c
Type=xfs
Unit file name must be "a-b-c.mount", /usr/lib/systemd/system/a-b-c.mount

Comment: This is all true, but it's completely useless to solve the problem.